# After update nginx / php doesnt work properly

Tags: php, nginx

I updated my raspberry pi to jessie (distupgrade). After this, I get the error below from my browser for requesting one site:

```
The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

    This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
```

I want access to moaDB (like phpmyadmin for mongoDB). PHPMyadmin is working fine after the update, moaDB not.

error.log of nginx:

```
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: collection in /var/www/moaDB/index.php on line 498" while reading upstream, client: 192.168.178.25, server: , request: "GET /moaDB/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "192.168.178.21"
```

why I get this error for this request and for phpmyadmin not?

Comment: the collection error is no real error, i only wanted to show that the error.log of nginx not shows any error...

Comment: open developer tools and look at what the redirection chain actually looks like

Comment: can you give  me a help how?

Comment: @Piet are you describing one or two problems?  Try to make cause/effect as clear as possible in your questions to get the best help (e.g. when I navigate to page xyz, I get this error in my browser and also this error in my NGINX log....).  It wouldn't hurt to include a bit of code and/or your NGINX configuration.

Comment: Redirect loop caused when a clean copy of MoaDB is installed with no database. Download v1.01